# Can you change a users selective sync with the Dropbox API through a web application?

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, data-synchronization

I've tried to read through the Dropbox API Documentation to see if this was possible but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Basically I want to know if the API has the ability to force a selective sync on a part of a dropbox account temporarily on a users computer.

So lets say you have a file structure like this:

- Dropbox

  - Folder A

    - Folder x
    - Folder y
    - Folder z
  - Folder B

    - Folder g
    - Folder h

So a user wants to work on the contents of what is in folder h so the web app forces the users local Dropbox folder to selectively sync only folder g.

The users local machine file structure would then look like this:

- Dropbox

  - Folder B

    - Folder g

Then the user can signal to the web app ( A button for simplicity sake ) that they are done and the selective sync removes the local folder.

I have no problems diving into the code solution, I just want to know if it is possible to to this, and if one is feeling generous a push in the right direction :).

Preferably in PHP as the web app I am looking at developing will be written in PHP on the back end.

Answer (score 0):

No, the API has no mechanism for Selective Sync.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, do you know if any cloud storage services offer this ability? Like Google Drive or Box?